# I want to set Password to have 4 characters Minimum

Tags: passwords

It's in ASP.NET C# programming language, I spend like 4 hours looking for solution, tried many ways but none of it works.

I have textbox which you can type in password and confirm password textbox.

I placed required field validator when user doesn't type anything to let him know he needs to type something, error pops up.

I want to have one more required field validator where it would be told to user that he needs to put 4 characters minimum in password field, if his password is less than 4 characters.

I tried every single possible way that I could come up with and stumble upon, nothing seems to be working!

Comment: FYI: Its considered polite to "accept" whatever answer works for you by clicking the checkmark under it's vote count.

Comment: Please provide a verifiable code example. You might have missed something simple, thus overcomplicating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try DataAnnotations.  apply the following lines of code to the Password property of the appropriate Class:

```
[Required][StringLength(MaxLength = arbitraryMaxLength, MinimumLength = 4)]
```

Comment: Other benefits include a built-in error message.  No need to code for it.

Comment: I don't understand this solution, problem is I don't even know how I would append this into error message afterwards

Comment: You don't append anything.  Data Annotations handle all that for you.  Here is a more in-depth tutorial on the subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: This is too complicated solution for me, I can't comprehend it unfortunately but it might be helpful with someone who is very experienced

Comment: Here's a easy to work through tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application  -  Bit out-of-date, but much easier to understand when compared to later versions.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check it out in more detailed fashion once I'll be doing at some project in company or something, at the moment I'm trying to build e-commerce website as a first project where I would be able to add it on my CV and hopefully get a job in some company. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Custom validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes I did and failed miserably. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a RegularExpressionValidator. Maybe [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/TextBox-Minimum-and-Maximum-Character-Length-Validation-using-ASPNet-RegularExpression-Validators.aspx) helps.

Comment: YES finally!!! I did it under 10 seconds with your help, can't believe I lost whole day by trying to figure this out, I never used regular expressions at all, I should read some about them, definitely helpful!